# Parallel Joints in ROS

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, ros-melodic, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I work on a team that creates a humanoid robot, and we are currently making the much-procrastinated change to port over to ROS. However, the robot has multiple parallel joints in the legs, and I believe that URDF cannot define such a robot model (Correct me if I'm wrong). I have an SDF model of the robot, but I'm not able to find any good resources on how to control a robot through SDF, how to spawn it in gazebo, and what limitations I may face in the future based on this.

I was hoping someone could enlighten me about what exactly I'm getting into here, since content related to this is sparse. Thanks in advance!

For reference, we work on ROS melodic and gazebo9. The robot was modelled in SolidWorks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331624/parallel-joints-in-ros/) by [favre49](https://answers.ros.org/users/45175/favre49/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There isn't an ideal solution, but one workaround involves [mimic joints](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18623/whats-the-right-way-to-do-mimic-joints/)

[a tutorial](https://github.com/mintar/mimic_joint_gazebo_tutorial)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2019-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0